# Flutter - Gradle build failed in Linux after AndroidX migration

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I cannot run my project in my Linux machine (OpenSuse) after I migrated it to AndroidX, but the same project (with the same settings) works fine in Windows and Mac. They all use the same flutter channel and have the same versions. I tried everything, including cleaning and repairing packages, but nothing worked.

This is the error when I run the project:

```
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /home/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-5.2.1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/urllauncher/WebViewActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Finished with error: Gradle build failed to produce an Android package.
```

and this is the error when I run `flutter run -v`

```
.....
[        ] > Task :url_launcher:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
[        ] > Task :url_launcher:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
[        ] > Task :url_launcher:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
[        ] > Task :url_launcher:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug
[        ] > Task :url_launcher:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForDebug
[+1295 ms] > Task :app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDevelopmentDebug
[ +300 ms] > Task :app:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDevelopmentDebug
[        ] Unable to strip library '/home/Projects/Flutter/App/flutter_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs/development/debug/0/lib/armeabi/libcrashlytics.so' due to missing strip
tool for ABI 'ARMEABI'. Packaging it as is.
[        ] > Task :app:processDevelopmentDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
[ +499 ms] > Task :app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDevelopmentDebug
[+3600 ms] > Task :app:packageDevelopmentDebug
[        ] > Task :app:assembleDevelopmentDebug
[        ] 159 actionable tasks: 142 executed, 17 up-to-date
[ +833 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDevelopmentDebug'... (completed in 32.8s)
[  +20 ms] "flutter run" took 37,070ms.
Gradle build failed to produce an Android package.

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:28:3)
#1      _buildGradleProjectV2 (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:758:7)
#2      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:71:64)
#3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
#6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:678:45)
#7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
#8      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:522:5)
#9      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:30:15)
#10     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:288:13)
#11     runCommandAndStreamOutput (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart)
#12     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:71:64)
#13     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#14     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#15     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
#16     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:678:45)
#17     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
#18     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:522:5)
#19     Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:552:7)
#20     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#21     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#22     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
#23     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:963:23)
#24     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#25     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#26     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:116:13)
#27     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:173:5)
```

Comment: open the _android_ folder which is located in your flutter project directory in android studio as a project, then try to run it. This will give you more understandable error. Post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using flavor dimensions. The problem is that in Linux, Flutter is only allowed to use lowercase letters to name the flavors. I changed the names of flavors from `myFlavor` to `myflavor` and added in the android section in `app/build.gradle` this:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = "${project.archivesBaseName}-${variant.productFlavors.name.join()}-${variant.buildType.name}.apk"
    }
}
```

and everythign worked fine in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only a Android developer, but `armeabi` was removed in the past.
Please give a filter-it-out a try by

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    abiFilters "x86", "armeabi-v7a"
}
```